# DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix

I am writing contract for Ico and facing few declartion error as quoted

```
browser/mycontract.sol:64:27: DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique.
contract StandardToken is ERC20, BasicToken {
                          ^---^

browser/mycontract.sol:64:34: DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique.
contract StandardToken is ERC20, BasicToken {
                                 ^---^
```

This is my complete code below. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
 pragma solidity ^0.4.18;


/**
 * @title Ownable
 * @dev The Ownable contract has an owner address, and provides basic authorization control
 * functions, this simplifies the implementation of "user permissions".
 */
contract Ownable {
  address public owner;


  event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);


  /**
   * @dev The Ownable constructor sets the original `owner` of the contract to the sender
   * account.
   */
  function Ownable() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }


  /**
   * @dev Throws if called by any account other than the owner.
   */
  modifier onlyOwner() {
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    _;
  }


  /**
   * @dev Allows the current owner to transfer control of the contract to a newOwner.
   * @param newOwner The address to transfer ownership to.
   */
  function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public onlyOwner {
    require(newOwner != address(0));
    OwnershipTransferred(owner, newOwner);
    owner = newOwner;
  }

}












/**
 * @title Standard ERC20 token
 *
 * @dev Implementation of the basic standard token.
 * @dev https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20
 * @dev Based on code by FirstBlood: https://github.com/Firstbloodio/token/blob/master/smart_contract/FirstBloodToken.sol
 */
contract StandardToken is ERC20, BasicToken {

  mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) internal allowed;


  /**
   * @dev Transfer tokens from one address to another
   * @param _from address The address which you want to send tokens from
   * @param _to address The address which you want to transfer to
   * @param _value uint256 the amount of tokens to be transferred
   */
  function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
    require(_to != address(0));
    require(_value <= balances[_from]);
    require(_value <= allowed[_from][msg.sender]);

    balances[_from] = balances[_from].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    allowed[_from][msg.sender] = allowed[_from][msg.sender].sub(_value);
    Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Approve the passed address to spend the specified amount of tokens on behalf of msg.sender.
   *
   * Beware that changing an allowance with this method brings the risk that someone may use both the old
   * and the new allowance by unfortunate transaction ordering. One possible solution to mitigate this
   * race condition is to first reduce the spender's allowance to 0 and set the desired value afterwards:
   * https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20#issuecomment-263524729
   * @param _spender The address which will spend the funds.
   * @param _value The amount of tokens to be spent.
   */
  function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
    Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Function to check the amount of tokens that an owner allowed to a spender.
   * @param _owner address The address which owns the funds.
   * @param _spender address The address which will spend the funds.
   * @return A uint256 specifying the amount of tokens still available for the spender.
   */
  function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public view returns (uint256) {
    return allowed[_owner][_spender];
  }

  /**
   * @dev Increase the amount of tokens that an owner allowed to a spender.
   *
   * approve should be called when allowed[_spender] == 0. To increment
   * allowed value is better to use this function to avoid 2 calls (and wait until
   * the first transaction is mined)
   * From MonolithDAO Token.sol
   * @param _spender The address which will spend the funds.
   * @param _addedValue The amount of tokens to increase the allowance by.
   */
  function increaseApproval(address _spender, uint _addedValue) public returns (bool) {
    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = allowed[msg.sender][_spender].add(_addedValue);
    Approval(msg.sender, _spender, allowed[msg.sender][_spender]);
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Decrease the amount of tokens that an owner allowed to a spender.
   *
   * approve should be called when allowed[_spender] == 0. To decrement
   * allowed value is better to use this function to avoid 2 calls (and wait until
   * the first transaction is mined)
   * From MonolithDAO Token.sol
   * @param _spender The address which will spend the funds.
   * @param _subtractedValue The amount of tokens to decrease the allowance by.
   */
  function decreaseApproval(address _spender, uint _subtractedValue) public returns (bool) {
    uint oldValue = allowed[msg.sender][_spender];
    if (_subtractedValue > oldValue) {
      allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = 0;
    } else {
      allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = oldValue.sub(_subtractedValue);
    }
    Approval(msg.sender, _spender, allowed[msg.sender][_spender]);
    return true;
  }

}





/**
 * @title Mintable token
 * @dev Simple ERC20 Token example, with mintable token creation
 * @dev Issue: * https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/issues/120
 * Based on code by TokenMarketNet: https://github.com/TokenMarketNet/ico/blob/master/contracts/MintableToken.sol
 */

contract MintableToken is StandardToken, Ownable {
  event Mint(address indexed to, uint256 amount);
  event MintFinished();

  bool public mintingFinished = false;


  modifier canMint() {
    require(!mintingFinished);
    _;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Function to mint tokens
   * @param _to The address that will receive the minted tokens.
   * @param _amount The amount of tokens to mint.
   * @return A boolean that indicates if the operation was successful.
   */
  function mint(address _to, uint256 _amount) onlyOwner canMint public returns (bool) {
    totalSupply = totalSupply.add(_amount);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_amount);
    Mint(_to, _amount);
    Transfer(address(0), _to, _amount);
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Function to stop minting new tokens.
   * @return True if the operation was successful.
   */
  function finishMinting() onlyOwner canMint public returns (bool) {
    mintingFinished = true;
    MintFinished();
    return true;
  }
}


contract BestpeersToken is MintableToken {
  string public name = "chiragmaliwal Token";
  string public symbol = "CMW";
  uint8 public decimals = 18;
}
```

**Note :** I Combined all local imports to one .sol file using [solidity-flattener](https://github.com/poanetwork/solidity-flattener)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You haven't included `ERC20` or `BasicToken` contracts which is why StandardToken can't inherit them (i.e. `contract StandardToken is ERC20, BasicToken` doesn't work because the compiler doesn't know what `ERC20` or `BasicToken` means).

You need to either include these contracts in your code manually or import them from a separate file, then your `StandardToken` contract will be able to inherit from them.

[See here](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#inheritance) for more information on inheritance

Comment: Thanks for your response.
But FYI I am using `zeppelin-solidity` for creating `crowdsale ico`.
And `StandardToken` is already import `ERC20` and `BasicToken` from the separate file.
Please have a look : https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/StandardToken.sol

Comment: In your code above you have not included the lines `import "./BasicToken.sol";
import "./ERC20.sol";` anywhere, but they are in lines 3 and 4 of the file you linked to. Have you removed them from your code?

Comment: I use this `https://github.com/oraclesorg/oracles-combine-solidity` to combined all the solidity files in one file .
I also update my question please have a look.

Comment: Your flattened contract clearly doesn't include the ERC20 or BasicToken contracts, so the flattener hasn't worked correctly. To fix this all you need to do is include the missing contracts (and any other contracts the missing contracts inherit from) in your code